# Plot circles with matplotlib from text file

Tags: python, file, matplotlib, plot, readfile

I'm trying to plot circles in matplotlib using a file as source of data, and I'm finding some difficulties.

This is my code

```
with open('DataSample2.txt', 'r') as file:
    file.readline()  # skip the first line
    xy = [[float(x) for x in line.split(' ')[:2]] for line in file]
    rad = [[float(x) for x in line.split(' ')[2:3]] for line in file]

    print(xy)
    print(rad)

    #circle = plt.Circle(xy[0], rad[0], color='g')

    #fig = plt.gcf()

    #fig.gca().add_artist(circle)

    #fig.savefig('plotcircles.png')
```

And this is my data source:

```
x y rad
2 5 2
2 2 2
3 1 3
5 2 1
6 4 3
```

My problem, probably, is how I am creating the xy and rad lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need list to plot circles.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import rand

with open('DataSample2.txt', 'r') as f:
    next(f)
    xmin = ymin = 999999999
    xmax = ymax = -999999999
    for line in f:
        x, y, r = map(float, line.split())
        circle = plt.Circle((x, y), r, color=rand(3))
        fig = plt.gcf()
        fig.gca().add_artist(circle)
        xmin = min(x-r, xmin)
        xmax = max(x+r, xmax)
        ymin = min(y-r, ymin)
        ymax = max(y+r, ymax)
        #break # if you want draw only one circle, break here.
    plt.xlim(xmin, xmax)
    plt.ylim(ymin, ymax)
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is what I want, with one exception. How can I change the color for each circle? can I index a color array with "lines?"

Comment: @marco, I don't see any color list/array in your code. Define predefined colors and iterating it using `zip` or `enumerate`. Or use `numpy.random.rand` as I did in the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like this is better:

```
all_xy = []
all_rad = []

with open('DataSample2.txt', 'r') as file:
    file.readline()  # skip the first line
    for line in file:
        vals = line.split()
        all_xy.append([float(x) for x in vals[:2]])
        all_rad.append(float(vals[-1]))


print(all_xy)
print(all_rad)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However with this code xy and rad have only one value after the for cycle.

Comment: That's because they change value for every line of the file. When you exit the for loop they should have last line's values. If you want all of the values you have to store them. Edited.

Comment: `strip()` is not necessary. [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) without argument removes leading, trailing spaces.